# How do I block php debug output from being committed in svn?

Tags: php, debugging, svn, pre-commit-hook

I would like to block debug functions `var_dump, print_r, etc...` from being commited to the repo so that QA can go over things and not report bugs like "There is a huge block of text on all of the pages!!"

I have tried regex (not a great idea... presumably).

I have also tried `token_get_all` but for some reason, it returns `T_STRING` for each of the debug functions, which I guess would work, but it seems odd...

Is there a third better way?

Comment: you can use a global Constant `C_DEBUG` and wrap your debug tests in an `if C_DEBUG...` block. That won't litteraly *prevent* from comitting but if you don't forget to change `C_DEBUG` to false before a commit, it won't be displayed to the user

Comment: Ya, I was thinking of adding a meta function that would check if it was your user_id and then spit out the debug info...

Comment: I have a build tool that checks with a regex for `var_dump` and `print_r` as well as for commented-out code. Works pretty well, however it's a manual call prior to commit so the developer can check their own code before committing.

Comment: @JMax That still means training people to do something other than what they have been doing for years...

Comment: @hakre Any reason that build tool couldn't be set up as a precommit hook?

Comment: Because it's interactive. But as it's regex based and works pretty well, could be done. But mind the false positives you can have with static code analysis (even if you use the PHP tokennizer, `T_STRING` is correct btw., it's a string token (not a PHP string variable) containing the function name, do a syntax check first (lint)).

Comment: @hakre I see, I was expecting it to come out as `T_FUNCTION` instead as it is a function...

Comment: IIRC `T_FUNCTION` stands for the `function` keyword.

Comment: @hakre Ah, that makes sense, maybe this will work then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my new understanding, this is what I have:

```
$debug_functions = array('print_r', 'var_dump', 'var_export');

foreach($files as $file=>$ext){
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
    //break the content into tokens
    $tokens = token_get_all($file_contents);
    foreach($tokens as $t){
        //if the token id is an int (sometimes it isn't)
        if(is_int($t[0])){
            //if it matches our debug stuff...
            if($t[0] == T_STRING && (in_array($t[1], $debug_functions) || preg_match('/xdebug_.*?/', $t[1]))){
                echo 'Debug output '. $t[1] . ' found on line '. $t[2] . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but I highly recommend you remove all the print_r, var_dump etc from your code.

1. Keep your code clean all the time
2. Those tags are for debugging purposes only.
3. when you are committing, you should ensure everything works as expected. Altering commit code or having different code on your machine than the live machine ensures of bugs and issues.

So remove those tags, don't keep them in your code, **not even on a local machine**.

Comment: Heh, not really possible... 4 devs, I don't have control over their code. I want to prevent mistaken commits.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a sniff [PHP_CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/php_codesniffer) and make SVN execute it as a pre-commit hook. This would reject committing such code.

Comment: An interesting option, we aren't using phpcs just yet. I plan to add that as a post commit hook at some point, no point in blocking if it doesn't follow the guidelines, but telling them it doesn't afterwards seems like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way is not using var_dump and related functions at all.
Coding better practices includes

1. Unit testing with [PHPUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPUnit) and
2. Using a remote debugger, for example [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote)

Comment: Still have to block them from committing `xdebug_*` functions then (which is included in my solution).

Comment: Edited answer. I meant to debug through GUI ("remote debug")